# $x=0$: A Condition Proof

Tags: inequality

I'm asked to prove that if $x\geq 0$ and $x\leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$, then $x=0$, but I'm not sure where to go. I have that the logically equivalent statement is
$$x\neq 0\implies\exists\epsilon\leq0~\text{s.t.}~x<0\lor x>\epsilon,$$
but what does this tell me?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Suppose that $x > 0$, and consider $$\epsilon := \frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: $x\leq\frac{x}{2}$???

Comment: @Trancot Yes. Rearranging, conclude that $2x \le x$; is this possible?

Comment: What is the setup though? I think you are hinting at a contradictory setup, but what's the setup?

Comment: "Suppose $x > 0$, intending a contradiction. Do stuff, and conclude $2x \le x$, leading to..."

Comment: No I meant to show $P$ is true show that $\neg P\implies \perp$, but I've got it now.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few techniques of proof. One of them is called proof by contradiction. Where you assume the negation, and show it is impossible (arrive at a contradiction). So in this case suppose $x \ne 0$, by assumption this means $x > 0$ now from the hint your given by T.Bongers, you should be able to arrive at a contradiction.

Keep in mind your two assumptions are $x \ge 0$ and  $x \le \epsilon. $ If $\epsilon = \frac{x}{2}$ then by assumption $x \le \frac{x}{2}$ but there is only one $x$ that satisfies this inequality, if you think about what that x must be, you will see the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've got from what you've all said:

Assume that $x>0$, and let $\epsilon=\frac{x}{2}$, but by assumption $x\leq \epsilon$, namely $x\leq \frac{x}{2}$, but since $x>0$, then division by $x$ on both sides produces a contradiciton, namely that $1\leq \frac{1}{2}$, and so it must be true that if $x\geq 0$ and $x\leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But please do break it up into more than one sentence.

Comment: Perhaps someone wouldn't mind critiquing this.

Comment: Oh, OK. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are kinda using the contrapositive, really: if $x>0$ we can find *one* $\epsilon >0$; namely $\epsilon =x/2 >0$ (or really $x/\alpha$ for any $\alpha >1$ you like) such that $$0<\frac x 2 <x $$ Thus you have proven that $x\leq \epsilon$ *for each* $\epsilon >0$ implies $x\leq 0$. The additional hypothesis that $x\geq 0$ implies that $x=0$. Observe how $$\neg (\forall \epsilon >0\;\; x\leq \epsilon)=\exists \epsilon >0(\epsilon <x)$$

Comment: @Trancot Yes, looks good. Note that since $x>0$, we're allowed to let $\epsilon=x/2$, since $x/2$ is positive. Does it make sense why we don't need to consider the case when $x<0$?